# Update query in MySQL and PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql

PHP usually works pretty much straight out of the box, but I cannot get this query to work. I am attempting to update a simple record. My code is as follows.

```
<?php

 $customername=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customername']); 
 $contact=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']); 
 $customerorder=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customerorder']); 
 $orderplaced=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['orderplaced']); 
 $staffmember=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['staffmember']); 
 $daterequired=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['daterequired']); 
 $status=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']); 
 $paid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['paid']); 
 $delivery=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delivery']); 
 $ordercontent=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ordercontent']); 
 $orderid=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['orderid']); 

mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxxxxx") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("xxxxxx")or die("Connection Failed");


$query = "UPDATE ordermanager_orders SET customername='$customername', contact='$contact',  ordernumber='$customerorder', placedby='$orderplaced', requiredby='$daterequired', status=$status', staffmember='$staffmember', paid='paid', delivery='$delivery', ordercontent='$ordercontent' WHERE order='$orderid'";

if(mysql_query($query)){
 echo "updated";}
 else{
 echo "fail";}

?>
```

The values are being posted or "Getted" from another page. They are definitely coming through as otherwise it comes up with errors. At the moment it simply comes up with 'failed' as per the code.

I have tried numerous variants of code found on the internet, to check if my coding was correct, however I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: There are no error messages showing from mysql, however I'm not sure how to use the echo method to check??

Comment: Always in these cases: echo out your query and copy-and-paste it into a database session (MySQL on the console, or phpMyAdmin). As others have pointed out, you have an error in your SQL.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if u have tried to print_r your $query to check.

1st. Shift your connection string to the top most.

2nd. `status=$status'` <<=== less 1 quote

Answer (score 3):

I thought you had to connect to the database before you were able to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`? Try connecting above all other code.

The status section of the query is also missing a quote mark.

Comment: You're right. You can't use mysql_real_escape_string without a valid connection.

Comment: I have pushed the connection to the top of the code, however the same error occurs....

Comment: echo $query and paste it into phpmyadmin to see what it tells you.

Comment: Got it sorted, apparently I named one of my columns incorrectly.... no wonder no one here spoted it. Thanks everyone for your help anyhow.... so glad I got this sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because of not handling your `status` update correctly: `status=$status'` must be `status='$status'`.

You would have figured this if you'd put a `mysql_error()` in your 'fail' section.

Comment: I have changed the status problem with no avail

Answer (score 1):

Try changing by adding a comma

`status=$status'` to `status='$status'`

And FYI change `paid='paid'` to `paid='$paid'` to ensure the correct value is passed